# What do I need to do that I can access google calendar on thunderbird?

Tags: thunderbird, google-calendar, calendar

I tried to install the provider plugin for thunderbird, but it said my release was too old. I have the lastest release of thunderbird in the lucid archives.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### For Ubuntu 10.10+

Installing the necessary components is just a matter of running:

```
sudo apt-get install xul-ext-lightning xul-ext-gdata-provider
```

This will install the Lightning Calendar extension and the Google Calendar provider.

#### For Ubuntu 10.04

Unfortunately, Lightning is not available in the Ubuntu repositories for 10.04 LTS users. If you are running Ubuntu 10.04 LTS, you have 2 options:

1. 32-bit users can install a version of Lightning compatible with Thunderbird 3.1 from https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/thunderbird/addon/lightning/versions/?page=1#version-1.0b2
2. You can install the latest stable version of Thunderbird, following the instructions in [How do I install the latest stable version of Thunderbird?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/50931/how-do-i-install-the-latest-stable-version-of-thunderbird). The thunderbird-stable PPA also has a compatible version of the Lightning extension for Ubuntu 10.04 LTS users.

I would strongly discourage disabling the addons compatibility checker, as advised in another answer. The check is there for a very good reason, and disabling it could make Thunderbird unusable.

Answer (score 6):

I just tried it out, and you'll need

1. [Lightning](https://addons.mozilla.org/en/thunderbird/addon/2313/)
2. [Provider for Google Calendar](https://addons.mozilla.org/en/thunderbird/addon/4631/)

To disable compatibility checking for extensions, open Thunderbird's preferences, switch to the "Advanced" tab and in the "General" subtab, start the config editor. ([source](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Modify_Thunderbird_settings))

[image: Where to find the Config Editor]

Add a new boolean value via right click named

```
extensions.CompatibilityCheck.[VERSION]
```

set to false.

`[VERSION]` stands for your Thunderbird version, e.g. `3.1`, if you're using 3.1 stable, `3.1a` if you're using 3.1 alpha, or `3.1b` if you're using 3.1 beta. ([source](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Updating_extensions))

Then you can just install your extensions.

Should the Config Editor be unavailable for any reason whatsoever, you can always manually edit `~/.mozilla-thunderbird/[somecharacters].default/prefs.js`.

Add the following lines as necessary:

```
user_pref("extensions.checkCompatibility", false);
user_pref("extensions.checkCompatibility.3.0", false);
```

Comment: the default thunderbird does not seem to have this configuration option.

Comment: Updated. The indicated button is unavailable? Version `3.0.6+build2+nobinonly-0ubuntu0.10.04.1` from lucid-updates shows me this button. Alternatively you edit `~/.mozilla-thunderbird/[somecharacters].default/prefs.js` by hand.

Answer (score 2):

You need the 'Lightning' extension for Thunderbird (http://www.mozilla.org/projects/calendar/)
 and the google provider plugin (https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/thunderbird/addon/4631/).

You can then ask the creation of a new "network" calendar, and identify it using the "private URL" that Google Calendar gives you (in the calendar's preferences).

Answer (score 0):

if you have a fairly new thunderbird + lightning combination (or the standalone calendar program sunbird) you can use caldev to have a two-way sync.

for a detailed explanation and howto you can read [this blogpost](http://pthree.org/2010/10/18/synchronize-mozilla-lightning-with-google-calendar/) by aaron toponce